# Printing from method that has a Stack

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have created a method that places 3 star wars tickets in a group of 7 tickets randomly to create a total of 10 tickets. I also have to create a method that will assign the ticket to the next person in "Line". When I try to print it out it throws a EmptyStackException and I am unsure as to why. Is there a way that I have to move the Stack to the main method?

Here is my code so far and am just wondering where I have gone wrong. Please guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;


public class movieRaffle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    queue.offer("Megan");
    queue.offer("Kate");
    queue.offer("Conan");
    queue.offer("Jay");
    queue.offer("Bert");
    queue.offer("Ernie");
    queue.offer("Mickey");
    queue.offer("Goofy");
    queue.offer("Optimus");
    queue.offer("Megatron");

    Stack<String> ticketList = new Stack<>();

    while(queue.size() > 0)
    System.out.println(queue.remove() + " wins tickets to " + ticketList.pop());

}

public static void ticketList() {
    Stack<String> tickets = new Stack<String>();
    tickets.push("Olympus Has Fallen");
    tickets.push("Jurassic Park");
    tickets.push("The Patriot");
    tickets.push("Matrix");
    tickets.push("Gettysburg");
    tickets.push("Gods and Generals");
    tickets.push("White House Down");
    tickets.add((int) (Math.random() * 10), "Star Wars");
    tickets.add((int) (Math.random() * 10), "Star Wars");
    tickets.add((int) (Math.random() * 10), "Star Wars");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that right now you are creating an empty `Stack`.  Your `ticketList()` method should return the `Stack` it creates.

```
public static Stack<String> ticketList() {
    ...
    ...
    return tickets;
}
```

Then when you create your `Stack` in your `main`, you can do it like this:

```
Stack<String> ticketList = ticketList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have creaed an empty  `Stack<String> ticketList = new Stack<>();` 
 but you not called the ticketList() method to add the  value to it.

You need to do like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<String> ticketList = new Stack<>(); 
    ticketList(Stack<String> tickets ) ; calling the method 
}
```

Please change you method like below and remove `Stack<String> tickets = new Stack<String>();` within the method.

```
public static void ticketList(Stack<String> tickets ) {

}
```

Comment: When I do 

    ticketList(Stack<String> tickets);

it becomes a Unresolved compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `return type` of `ticketList()` method to `Stack<String>`:

```
public static Stack<String> ticketList() {
        Stack<String> tickets = new Stack<String>();
        ...
        return tickets;
    }
```

and then assign the returned value to `ticketList` in your main method:

```
Stack<String> ticketList = ticketList();
```